# How to find parent element from knowing child

Tags: python, appium

So i have this element:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.LinearLayout[@resource-id=\'blabla\'')
```

And i want to find its parent.

This is what i have try (until now not working):

```
parent = element.find_element_by_xpath(/..android.widget.LinearLayout[@resource-id=\'some_id\'')
```

Comment: Try: `..\andriod`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line of code

```
parent = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@resource-id='blabla']/..")
```

Comment: The probelem is that i already have the child element, i am search the chile element by scroll with UiSelector because this is list so this scroll down automatically

Comment: can you specify your goal ? why you need to find the parent node'

Comment: This is table with several columns and the child element is the text that i am looking for in order to get the relevant row

Comment: I think your approach is wrong why don't you loop through the table

for el in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("table")

Comment: Because several rows and visible only when scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"
                + ".resourceId(\"android:id/list\")).scrollIntoView("
                + "new UiSelector().text(\"blabla\"));");
```

Comment: This found the element only if its visible, if the element i down in the list this is not auto scroll

Comment: yes but this scroll only very very little part of the screen and not all the screen down

Comment: can you post the screenshot or video so that i can see what i can help you